# Probability of word LOLLIES

Tags: probability

Consider this probability question.

"A four letter 'word' is chosen randomly from the letters of the word LOLLIES. What is the probability of this word containing exactly one L?"

Now computing the total number of 4 letters words is straightforward by considering cases.

**Case #1:** The word contains 3 L's

**Case #2:** The word contains 2 L's

**Case #3:** The word contains no repetition.

However, I feel that as tempting as it may be to do the following, it is not correct.

**P(Exactly one L) = (Number of words with exactly one L)/(Total number of words).**

Because the events are no longer equally likely depending on the case.

So how would you go about doing this problem? My gut feeling is telling me that it is far simpler than initially perceived using combinations. But could this please be confirmed?

Comment: There is ambiguity in the question. Are $4$ (Scrabble) letters chosen at random from the $7$? Or are all the distinct $4$-letter words written down, and then one of them is chosen at random, with all equally likely?

Comment: I believe that the question intended for the latter.

Comment: As Andre Nicolas has pointed out, the question is ambiguous.  The answer according to the second interpretation is 6/13 (as in barak manos's answer), and according to the first interpretation is 12/35 (as in the other two answers).  My guess is that the second interpretation was intended, as you indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of L's in the chosen word. Then $$P\left\{ X=k\right\} =\binom{3}{k}\binom{4}{4-k}\binom{7}{4}^{-1}$$

This under the assumption that a specific letter cannot be chosen twice and that any letter has the same probability to be chosen. Here the $3$ L's are looked at as **distinct** letters.

The $3$ corresponds with the number of L's in LOLLIES and the upper $4$ with the number of non-L's. The lower $4$ corresponds with the number of letters that are chosen, and $7$ with the total number of letters in LOLLIES.

For special case $k=1$ this leads to $P(X=1)=\frac{12}{35}$

Comment: Can you explain why there is a $\binom{3}{k}$? If all the L's are identical, then why is it that we must choose them?

Comment: If there are $3$ $L$'s (let's say $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$) then choosing e.g. $2$ of them can be done in $\binom{3}{2}=3$ ways: $(L_1,L_2)$, $(L_1,L_3)$ and $(L_2,L_3)$. These ways have equal probability.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the total number of different $4$-letter words:

- Number of words with L-count equal $0$ is $\dfrac{4!}{0!}\cdot{\dbinom{4}{4}}=24$
- Number of words with L-count equal $1$ is $\dfrac{4!}{1!}\cdot{\dbinom{4}{3}}=96$
- Number of words with L-count equal $2$ is $\dfrac{4!}{2!}\cdot{\dbinom{4}{2}}=72$
- Number of words with L-count equal $3$ is $\dfrac{4!}{3!}\cdot{\dbinom{4}{1}}=16$

So the probability of choosing a word containing exactly one L is $\dfrac{96}{24+96+72+16}=\dfrac{6}{13}$

---

The solution above is under the assumption that the order of the letters in the word matters.

Comment: I believe that this is the 'common trap' that I was tempted to fall for when doing this problem.

Comment: @Trogdor: The order of the letters in the word is important, correct? What is the trap in that case (i.e., where do you think it is wrong)?

Comment: Correct. For choosing the sample space, the order is important. However, for satisfying the condition of having one L, I imagine that the order is not important because the order of the letters does not change the number of L's we have.

I believe that the mistake could be the fact that you did the question as "P(Number of ways to get one L)=(number of ways to get one L)/(Total 4 letter words), which may be fallacious because there are different cases, so each event is not equally likely.

Comment: @Trogdor: The way I see it, "A four letter 'word' is chosen randomly from the letters" means that, for example LOIE and ELOI are **two different samples**. That's how I count the number of words in each of the bullets above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the probability of exactly one L like this:

Let's take the case that the first letter was an L. There is a $\frac{3}{7}$ probability of this. (Of $7$ possible letters, $3$ are Ls.) Then there is a $\frac{4}{6}$ probability that the second letter is *not* L, $\frac{3}{5}$ for the third, and $\frac{2}{4}$ for the fourth. The probability that only the first letter is an L is therefore $\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{4} = \frac{3}{35}$.

It shouldn't be difficult to show that there is a $\frac{3}{35}$ probability for the L to be the second, third, or fourth letter instead.

So the total probability that there is exactly one L is $\frac{3}{35} + \frac{3}{35} + \frac{3}{35} + \frac{3}{35} = \frac{12}{35}$.